# Recommendet tool (plugin) for software reuse in Java

Tags: software-development, java

I am looking for a tool (or plugin) which can help me in doing software reuse in Java.

Recently, I worked with **Merobase** and its Eclipse plugin **[Code Conjurer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/code-conjurer)**. It helps to find a desired feature based on a defined set of test cases. However, it is not as good as it should be and it is so dependent on names of class, method, and etc. defined in the test cases.

I also recently read a paper **[Systematizing Pragmatic Software Reuse](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~rtholmes/papers/tosem_2012_holmes.pdf)** which introduces an Eclipse plugin **Gilligan** which was exactly what I need. The plugin helps the developers to do the software reuse task in Java. Very good paper. However, the plugin is not available for public. I have emailed the authors of the paper about the plugin and they wrote to me that it was a prototype and not available for public and so no more experiment. )-:

Please let me know if any one is aware of any tools or plugin which can help to makes the process of reuse more easier (helps to select a desired feature, finding all its dependency, and etc.).

Comment: Does it have to work with Eclipse?

Comment: It must work with Java, but not necessarily with Eclipse. However, it is useful to know about any tools in other languages. It helps me to know the area better.